# How to show a table in an alert iOS

Tags: ios

So I have a label, and when I click on it, I want it to show sort of a table in an "alert" type pop-up window that allows you to **scroll** (since there will be quite a few lines of data) through values like this:

```
1) some value : correct
2) Some other value : incorrect
```

The data I have is stored in two different `NSMutableArray`s.

I know I can make an alert show with some code like this,

```
 UIAlertView *message = nil;

        message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Definition"
                                             message:definition
                                            delegate:nil
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
```

Is it possible to do this? If so, what should I look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a very bad solution - why not use modal controller instead?

Anyway, you can always add a subview to `UIAlertView`. However, note that changing its size could be complicated.

Comment: I don't really need to change the size of it, just as long as they can see all the data. And what do you mean by use a modal controller?

Comment: LMGTFY links are blocked for a reason.